# How to split a binary file into different frames

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, signal-processing, kinect

So I have a quite big binary file that contains the information of about 70 video frames.

I read the binary file into MATLAB using the following

```
fid = fopen('data.binary');
B = fread(fid,'int64');
fclose(fid);
```

But then the variable `B` still contains a huge number of data.  So I was wondering how can we split the variable B such that I can get data from one frame only one by one.  Like let's say 30 FPS.

Is that even possible?

Thanks

PS: the pixel precision is uint8 and the Frame size 424X512. This is the code I am using:

```
fid = fopen('C:\KinectData\Depth\Depth_Raw_0.binary');
B = fread(fid,'uint8');
fclose(fid);

B = uint8(B);

Z = B(1:217088)

n = 424; % No. of columns of T
BB = reshape(Z, n,[]);

BB = uint8(BB);

imshow(BB)
```

But the picture isn't quite there yet.

Comment: Do you know the size of each frame?  It will be impossible to reconstruct your frame sequence unless you know what this is.  Also, what is the precision of each pixel? `uint8`? `uint16`? `int64` is definitely not possible as there is no standard that I know of for video that has 64 bits per pixel.  Is this a **colour** video or a **grayscale** video?  If this is colour, are the colour pixels interleaved, or are the colour channels separated by plane?  You need to give a lot more information before we / I can answer.

Comment: @rayreng Hi Thanks for replying. The size of the frame is 512x412. The video is a grayscale video. So I just want each frame as a picture so I can process it individually on MATLAB.I am not too sure about the pixel precision. The code I am using is from here: http://kinectstreamsaver.codeplex.com/ bottom of the page and yes the depth video is from the Kinect for XBOX one.

Comment: OK, I see the code below.  Yes, it's possible to read in 1 frame at a time but I don't know how that data is structured.  It looks like you are reading in from multiple streams in a single frame.  Also, the code you have referenced looks like it's trying to read in quaternion data, and not depth data.  Can you please clarify?

Comment: The code I referenced is trying to give the output of the joint coordinates. However, I am not really interested in that. I just want to process the depth image of inmate object. So instead of fid = fopen('C:\KinectData\Skel\liTimeStamp.binary'); I just using fopen('C:\KinectData\Depth_data.binary') which contains only the depth data and nothing else.

Comment: @rayeng hi again.I now understand that you were saying about the data type. So the pixel precision is uint8 and not int64 and the resolution per frame is 424X512. So this is the code I used: See edits. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: OK, that makes sense.  I'll write up something for you.  Give me a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so we know a few things given your comments:

1. Each frame is 424 x 512
2. The precision of each element in your video is `uint8`
3. This is a grayscale video, so colour is not going to be considered
4. I'm going to assume your data is read in row major format.  Bear in mind that MATLAB reads in data in column major format if you want to read in the data as a matrix, so you'll have to do a transpose operation, and ensure that you read the data into a transposed matrix first.

What I'm going to do is put each frame into a [`cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell.html) entry inside a cell array.  The reason why I'm doing this is because we don't know how many frames are really in your sequence.  You said "70 or so" frames, and since we don't know the exact number, we will dynamically populate the cell array as we go.

The code you have written will predominantly be the same, but we're going to run a `while` loop until what we read in from file is empty.  In the `while` loop, we will read one frame at a time and store it into the cell array.  I'll also make a counter that counts the number of frames we have to for later, and you'll see why. As such:

```
%// Open the file
fid = fopen('C:\KinectData\Depth\Depth_Raw_0.binary');
col = 424; %// Change if the dimensions are not proper
row = 512;

frames = {}; %// Empty cell array - Put frames in here
numFrames = 0; %// Let's record the number of frames too
while (true) %// Until we reach the end of the file:
    B = fread(fin, [col row],'uint8=>uint8'); %// Read in one frame at a time

    if (isempty(B)) %// If there are no more frames, get out
        break;
    end

    frames{end+1} = B.'; %// Transpose to make row major and place in cell array
    numFrames = numFrames + 1; %// Count frame
end

%// Close the file    
fclose(fid);
```

As such, if you want to access the i<sup>th</sup> frame, you would simply do:

```
frm = frames{i};
```

As an additional bonus, you can play this as a [`movie`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movie.html) in MATLAB.  What we can do is preallocate a movie structure that is compatible to play the movie, then when you run the `movie` command, this will play the frames for you.  Let's specify a frame rate of 10 fps, so that it will play slow enough to see the results.  Therefore, when you're done do something like this:

```
%// Preallocate the movie structure array 
movieFrames(numFrames) = struct('cdata',[],'colormap',[]);

for idx = 1 : numFrames
    img = frames{idx};
    movieFrames(idx) = im2frame(cat(3, img, img, img));
end
figure;
imshow(movieFrames(1).cdata); %// Show first frame to establish figure size
movie(movieFrames, 1, 10); %// Play the movie once at 10 FPS
```

Note that movies can only be played in colour, and so you would have to make your grayscale image artificially into colour.  A colour frame is a 3D matrix, where each 2D slice tells you the amount of red, green or blue.  For grayscale, each of these slices are the same, and so you would just replicate each grayscale frame for each slice.  I used [`cat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html) to make the grayscale frame into a 3D matrix.  I also use [`im2frame`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/im2frame.html) to convert each image into a movie frame structure compatible to be played with `movie`.

## Small caveat

I don't have access to your binary file, so this code is untested.  Use at your own risk!

Comment: Would something like this work with any video format?

Comment: @Canadian_Republican this only works for the specific format mentioned in the question. Any other video format would have to be reworked with using `VideoReader` for example. The documentation for loading in a video and reading it in frame by frame are quite good.